# Substituting Reference id in one table for field in another

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Im new to Rails and having trouble setting up the relationship to work with a simple reference ID.  I have a table for Recipes with a field for course selection that is an integer.  That integer refers to a table that is just a reference table for all the different possible courses.  How can i set up the relationship so that when I call recipe.course it returns the course name and not the id number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at has_many and belongs_to relations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

The associations you want are:
Recipe `belongs_to: :course`
Course `has_many: :recipes`

Then be sure to generate a migration to add `course_id` to Recipe. (Remember this with Rails: Convention over Configuration. The convention is to use `model_id` as the association column name.)

With both of these associations set and the database migrated correctly, `recipe.course` will return the instance of Course matching `recipe.course_id`. (You can then simply do `recipe.course.name` to get the Course name.)

You will also incedentally be able to do `course.recipes` and get the relation of all Recipes associated to that Course.

Comment: This worked perfect thanks....I had the relationship backwards in my head and was trying to do recipe has_one :course and that wasnt working.